How do I enable the "Require password after screen saver begins or display is turned off" feature on macOS Sequoia?
How do I enable the "Require password after screen saver begins or display is turned off" feature on macOS Sequoia?
Does anyone know how I can enable it?


I've figured it out. You need to open the settings for the iPhone Mirroring app and tick this option:

After I did that, the option mentioned in the question title is enabled.
